# Evaluating a Bessel function integral $\int \frac{K_v(x)^{a-1}}{K_v(-x)^{a+1}}dx$ for an inverse function’s Fourier series coefficients

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-numbers, fourier-series, inverse-function, bessel-functions

A transformation of [**Bessel Y Zero** $y_{v,x}$](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselYZero/)  [inverts $\arg H^{(1)}_v(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504465/can-we-manipulate-this-equation-to-get-the-inverse-of-the-hankel-function-of-the) with the [argument function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arg%28x%2By+i%29) and [the first Hankel function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=HankelH1). Also, another one  [inverts $\frac{Y_v(x)}{J_v(x)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5BBesselYZero%28e%2Catan%28x%29%2Fpi%2B1%29%2C10%5D%2Cx%3DBesselY%28e%2C2%29%2FBesselJ%28e%2C2%29) with [Bessel J](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Bessel+J) and [Bessel Y](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Bessel+Y). I am inexperienced with [**Fourier series**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html), but it gives a potentially interesting series of $y_{v,x+1}$. We use the ratio of Bessel functions for the first integral with, for simplicity, $|x|\le \frac L2,|L|<1$:

$$y_{v,x+1}=\frac1L \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2 y_{v,x+1}e^{-\frac{2\pi in x}L}dxe^\frac{2\pi i nx}L$$

Now substitute $x\to y_{v,x+1}$: $$\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2 y_{v,x+1}e^{-\frac{2\pi in x}L}dx=\frac1\pi\int_{y_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{y_{v,\frac L2+1}}x e^{-\frac{2in \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{Y_v(x)}{J_v(x)}\right)}L} d\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{Y_v(x)}{J_v(x)}\right)\right)$$

We simplify and use the polar form of complex numbers:

$$\frac1\pi\int_{y_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{y_{v,\frac L2+1}}x e^{-\frac{2in \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{Y_v(x)}{J_v(x)}\right)}L} d\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{Y_v(x)}{J_v(x)}\right)\right) = \frac2{\pi^2}\int_{y_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{y_{v,\frac L2+1}}\frac{\left(\frac{2i}{i-\frac{Y_v(x)}{J_v(x)}}-1\right)^\frac nL}{J_v^2(x)+Y_v^2(x)}dx$$

Here is $\arg\left(H_v^{(1)}(x)\right)$ representation with the [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), [second Hankel](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=abs%28HankelH1%28e%2Cx%29%29%5E%282*3%2Fcatalan-2%29%2FHankelH1%28e%2Cx%29%5E%282*3%2Fcatalan%29+vs+HankelH2%28e%2Cx%29%5E%283%2Fcatalan-1%29%2FHankelH1%28e%2Cx%29%5E%283%2Fcatalan+%2B1%29), and [Bessel K](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+HankelH2%28khinchin%2Cz%29%5E%284-1%29%2FHankelH1%28khinchin%2Cz%29%5E%284%2B1%29+vs++pi%5E2%2F4+%28-1%29%5E%284%28khinchin%2B1%29%29+%28BesselK%28Khinchin%2C+i+z%29%29%5E%284-1%29%2FBesselK%28Khinchin%2C+-i+z%29%5E%284%2B1%29) functions,  and the substitution $x\to y_{v,x+1}$:

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2 y_{v,x+1}e^{-\frac{2\pi in x}L}dx= \frac1\pi\int_{y_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{y_{v,\frac L2+1}} xe^{-\frac{2 in \arg\left(H_v^{(1)}(x)\right)}L}d\left(\arg\left(H_v^{(1)}(x)\right)\right)= \frac2{\pi^2}\int_{y_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{y_{v,\frac L2+1}} \frac{dx}{\text{sgn}^\frac{2n}L\left(H_v^{(1)}(x)\right) |H_v^{(1)}(x)|^2}dx=\frac2{\pi^2}\int_{y_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{y_{v,\frac L2+1}}\frac{| H_v^{(1)}(x)|^{\frac{2n}L-2}}{H_v^{(1)}(x)^\frac{2n}L}dx=\frac2{\pi^2}\int_{y_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{y_{v,\frac L2+1}}\frac{H^{(2)}_v(x)^{\frac nL-1}}{H_v^{(1)}(x)^{\frac nL+1}}dx=\frac i2(-1)^{v\left(\frac nL+1\right)+1}\int_{iy_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{iy_{v,\frac L2+1}}\frac{K_v(x)^{\frac nL-1}}{K_v(-x)^{\frac nL+1}}dx\end{align}$$

These coefficients are integrals over zeros of the imaginary part of powers and ratios of Bessel functions:

[**Proof of concept**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=besselyzero%282%2Cx%2B1%29%2Csum%5Be%5E%282+pi+i+n+x%29+Nintegrate%5B%282+e%5E%28-2+i+n+atan%28BesselY%282%2C+x%29%2FBesselJ%282%2C+x%29%29%29%29%2F%28%CF%80%5E2+%28BesselJ%282%2C+x%29%5E2+%2B+BesselY%282%2C+x%29%5E2%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C+5.135622307%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C-9%2C9%7D%5D)

[image]

How can you evaluate $\begin
{align}\displaystyle \frac i2(-1)^{v\left(\frac nL+1\right)+1}\int_{iy_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{iy_{v,\frac L2+1}}\frac{K_v(x)^{\frac nL-1}}{K_v(-x)^{\frac nL+1}}dx= \frac2{\pi^2}\int_{y_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{y_{v,\frac L2+1}}\frac{H^{(2)}_v(x)^{\frac nL-1}}{H_v^{(1)}(x)^{\frac nL+1}}dx =\frac2{\pi^2}\int_{y_{v,1-\frac L2}}^{y_{v,\frac L2+1}}\frac{\left(\frac{2i}{i-\frac{Y_v(x)}{J_v(x)}}-1\right)^\frac nL}{J_v^2(x)+Y_v^2(x)}dx\end{align}$ so we have an explicit series expansion of the Bessel Y zero function? If the complex Fourier series should not be used, then we take the imaginary and real parts of the integrals and use other Fourier series formulas:

1. A series expansion, or any form besides an integral, of any one of the integrals presented in this question will suffice.
2. If it helps, making the integrals indefinite and evaluating any one presented in this question is ok. Please do not approximate.

Comment: A slightly different series reduces to computing $\int_0^{j_{v,L}}\text{sgn}^\frac nL(H_v^{(1)}(t))dt=\int_0^{j_{v,L}}\left(\frac{H_v^{(1)}(t)}{H_v^{(2)}(t)}\right)^\frac n{2L}dt$ or $\int_0^b\left(\frac{K_v(t)}{K_v(-t)}\right)^a dt$. Maybe there is a way to get a recurrence relation?