# Is $f(x)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1L\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2f(t)\csc\bigl(\frac{\pi(t-x)}L\bigr)\sin\bigl(\frac{\pi(2m+1)(t-x)}L\bigr)dt$ true?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, solution-verification, fourier-series, fourier-restriction

A complex [Fourier series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html) converging on $|x|\le\frac L2$ is:

$$f(x)=\frac1L\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} e^\frac{2i\pi nx}L\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2 e^{-\frac{2\pi i nt}L}f(t)dt$$

Switching the sum and integral gives:

$$f(x)=\frac{\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}}L\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2 f(t)\sum_{n=-m}^m \frac{e^\frac{2\pi i nx}L}{e^\frac{2\pi i n t}L}dt$$

We [**simplify**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=fullsimplify%5Bexpand%5B%28-E%5E%28%28%282+I%29+Pi+x%29%2FL%29+%2B+E%5E%28%28%282+I%29+Pi+t%29%2FL%29+%28E%5E%28%28%282+I%29+Pi+%28t+-+x%29%29%2FL%29%29%5E%282+m%29%29%2F%28%28E%5E%28%28%282+I%29+Pi+%28t+-+x%29%29%2FL%29%29%5Em+%28E%5E%28%28%282+I%29+Pi+t%29%2FL%29+-+E%5E%28%28%282+I%29+Pi+x%29%2FL%29%29%29%5D%5D) using the [complex argument](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjO-vWauO_7AhWfD1kFHe1XAtMQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FArgument_(complex_analysis)&usg=AOvVaw3GnkXjEzffjXdA5u9yY9F7):

$$f(x)= \frac{\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}}L\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2 \frac{e^\frac{2\pi i t}L\left(e^\frac{2\pi i(t-x)}L\right)^{2m}-e^\frac{2\pi ix}L}{\left(e^\frac{2\pi i(t-x)}L\right)^m\left(e^\frac{2\pi i t}L-e^\frac{2\pi i x}L\right)}f(t)dt\mathop=^{L,m,t,x\in\Bbb R}=  \frac{\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}}L\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2  f(t)\csc\left(\frac{\pi(t-x)}L\right)\sin\left(m\arg\left(e^\frac{2\pi i (t-x)}L\right)+\frac{\pi(t-x)}L\right)dt\tag1$$

A test shows a [truncated Fourier series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=besselI%282%2Ce%29%2C+N%5B1%2F%282+pi%29+sum%5Be%5E%28i+n+e%29+Nintegrate%5BbesselI%282%2Ct%29++e%5E%28-i+n+t%29%2C%7Bt%2C-pi%2Cpi%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C-10%2C10%7D%5D%2C10%5D) equals its [integral representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=besselI%282%2Ce%29%2C+N%5B1%2F%282+pi%29+Nintegrate%5B%28e%5E%28-11+i+%28e+%2B+t%29%29+%28-e%5E%28i+%2822+e+%2B+t%29%29+%2B+e%5E%28i+%28e+%2B+22+t%29%29%29+BesselI%282%2C+t%29%29%2F%28-e%5E%28i+e%29+%2B+e%5E%28i+t%29%29+%2C%7Bt%2C-pi%2Cpi%7D%5D%2C10%5D). However, another simplification is:

$$f(x)\mathop=^?_{L,m,t,x>0} \frac{\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}}L\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2 f(t)\csc\left(\frac{\pi(t-x)}L\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi(2m+1)(t-x)}L\right)dt\tag 2$$

Surprisingly, the same numerical test with this integral gives a [**more accurate result**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=besselI%282%2Ce%29%2CNintegrate%5BbesselI%282%2Ct%29%28csc%28%28t+-+e%29%2F2%29+sin%28%2817+%28t+-+e%29%29%2F2%29%29%2F%282+%CF%80%29%2C%7Bt%2C-pi%2Cpi%7D%5D). The main goal of $(1),(2)$ is an explicit integral representation of inverse functions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522635/evaluating-a-bessel-function-integral-int-frack-vxa-1k-v-xa1dx).

Is there any way to simplify and correct restrictions on $(1),(2)$?

Comment: you can't switch sum and integral in general, even in the case that the Fourier series converges pointwise. To exchange sum and integral you need to add some stronger assumptions, as convergence in $L_1$

Answer (score 1):

From [Dirac $\delta(w)$ in DLMF 1.17.iii](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.17#iii):

$$f(x)=\frac1L\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} e^\frac{2\pi i nx}L\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2 e^{-\frac{2\pi i nt}L}f(t)dt=\frac1L\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2f(t)\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}e^{i n\frac{2\pi  }L(x-t)}dt$$

Invoke the Dirac delta function:

$$f(x)=\frac{2\pi}L\int_{-\frac L2}^\frac L2 \delta\left(\frac{2\pi}L(x-t)\right)f(t)dt$$

Which is just a modified [sifting property](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SiftingProperty.html)

Comment: Feel free to answer if there is a better one.